# Receive "must call the Connect-AzureAD" even I run it before

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

**My problem**

I try to run **Get-AzureADGroup** connected with an App Registration, but get this error message:

> Get-AzureADGroup : You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before
> calling any other cmdlets.

But what I am running is:

```
$secPasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $secret -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($appId , $secpasswd)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $cred -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $tenantId 

$gpe = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "group1"
```

**Connect-AzAccount** is run, so I don't understand this error message.

**My execution context**

I just created an App Registration and a secret to connect with.

**What I need**

- Why do I get this message since I run **Connect-AzureD**?
- What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: `Get-AzureADGroup` is in AzureAD module, which is loaded with `Connect-AzureAD`. `Connect-AzAccount` loads the Az.Accounts module.

Comment: AzureAD != Azure. Like the error states: you must first run Connect-AzureAD, not Connect-AzAccount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are helpful.

`Get-AzureADGroup` is under Azure AD module while `Connect-AzAccount` is under Az.Accounts module. They are different.

To run `Get-AzureADGroup`, you need to sign in with `Connect-AzureAD` which is the login command in Azure AD module.

If you don't want to install Azure AD module, you can choose to use [Get-AzADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadgroup?view=azps-5.8.0) instead of `Get-AzureADGroup`.